# Segmentation fault with GDB debugger - C

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am trying to "debug" this program using GDB debugger. I get the Segmentation fault (core dumped) when I execute the program.
This is my first time using GDB, so I do not really know what command to use or what to expect.

EDIT: I know what the error is. I need to find it using the GDB Debugger

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n, i;
    unsigned long long factorial = 1;

    printf("Introduzca un entero: ");
    scanf("%d",n);

    if (n < 0)
        printf("Error! Factorial de un numero negativo no existe.");

    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<=n; ++i)
        {
            factorial *= i;
        }
        printf("Factorial de %d = %llu", n, factorial);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",n);` --> `scanf("%d", &n);` Also `i=0;` --> `i=1;`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
scanf("%d",n);
```

As you wrote, n is declared as a variable of type int. What you want to do is to pass the address of n instead of n itself into the function.

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

To better understand the implementation of scanf(), check out stdio.h.

Also, set n = 1. Or otherwise the variable factorial will remain 0 regardless how many loops you've gone through.

EDIT: what you are trying to do to is to access a memory location passed in by the user, which is highly likely to map to a memory location that belongs to a completely different process or even OS. The segmentation fault is generated simply because the location is not accessible. What you can do in gdb is using **bt** in the gdb to a stack trace of segmentation fault.

Comment: Im not asking you to find the error visually. I mean using the GDB Debugger.

Comment: It's going to give you segmentation fault regardless if you use GDB or not. Do you mean how to use GDB to find track the problem?

Answer (score 1):

> I know what the error is. I need to find it using the GDB Debugger

You need to **read the [documentation of `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)** (and you should compile your source code with all warnings and debug info, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/); this puts [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debug information inside your executable).

The GDB user manual contains a [Sample GDB session](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Sample-Session.html#Sample-Session) section. You should read it carefully, and experiment `gdb`  in your terminal. The [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) will help you to run your program step by step, and to query its state (and also to analyze [`core` dumps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) post-mortem). Thus, you will understand what is happening.

<sup>Don't expect us to repeat what is in that tutorial section.</sup>

Try also the `gdb -tui` option.

<sup>PS. Don't expect StackOverflow to tell you what is easily and well documented. You are expected to find and read documentation before asking on SO.</sup>