# How can i debug the code with core dump using gdb?

Tags: c, terminal, gdb

This is a simple program regarding string operations but i encountered segmentation fault(core dump) during run time.

I am trying to run the program in terminal in the latest ubuntu version. 
Here is a snippet of the code...

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
char s1[50],s2[50];
int ch,i,j,l,l1,l2,flag,count1=0,count2=0;
do
{
printf("\n MENU \n");
printf("\n 1.String concatenation \n");
printf("\n 2.String comparison \n");
printf("\n 3.Substring \n");
printf("\n Enter a choice ..."); 
scanf("%d",ch);
switch(ch)
{
 case 1:
 printf("\n Enter the first string \n");
 gets(s1);
 printf("\n Enter the second string \n");
 gets(s2);
 for(int i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++)
```

the code is working till displaying the menu section but it shows segmentation fault( core dump) afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Segmentation fault with GDB debugger - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749834/segmentation-fault-with-gdb-debugger-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf("%d",ch); --> scanf("%d",&ch);
```

`scanf` takes address of variable where the valued to be stored.

read [man scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

**It specifies,**

> d  Matches an optionally signed decimal integer; the next pointer must
>   be a pointer to int.

Comment: And the OP will still not know how to use `gdb`.

Comment: @user202729 you are free to write to your own answer and teach him to how to use gdb. I considered that option as too board and solved specific problem OP had.

Comment: thank you... that worked but when i am tring to run the rest of the program my gets() function is not working.. any idea how to fix?

Comment: @user202729 Not kind.