# Segmentation Fault in typedef struct

Tags: c, flex-lexer

Im trying to make a sintax analyzer using FLEX and C, I implemented a stack, it works fine but when trying to access elements of the structure it returns a Segmentation Fault, I suppouse it has something to deal with the definition of the elements of the structure.

This is parser.h file

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H

void error();
bool analisis();

int tokenActual;

#endif
```

This is a parser.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "parser.h"
#include "pila.h"
#include "NuT.h"
#include "produccion.h"

extern int yylex();

typedef struct _symbol{
// Indica si es terminal o no terminal
short type;
// Representacion del simbolo en string
char *name;
// Indice del simbolo
short pos;
}sym;

// No terminales
sym *S_ = {NON_TERM,"S",0};
sym *SP_ = {NON_TERM,"SP",1};



//Terminales
sym *OR = {TERM,"v",2};     
sym *PROD = {TERM,"*",3};
sym *SUM = {TERM,"+",4};
sym *INTERR = {TERM,"?",5};
sym *A = {TERM, "a", 6};
sym *B = {TERM,"b",7};
sym *PI = {TERM,"(",8};
sym *PD = {TERM, ")", 9};
sym *EPS = {EPSILON,"ε",10};
sym *EOFF = {TERM,"$",11};
```

This is the NuT.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef NUT_H
#define NUT_H
#define TERM 1
#define NON_TERM 2
#define EPSILON 3
#endif

typedef struct _symbol sym;
```

pila.h file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "NuT.h"

typedef struct _nodo nodo;

typedef struct _Stack Stack;

/* Crea una nueva pila */
Stack* new_stack(void);

/* Permite introducir un elemento a una pila */
void push(Stack* pila, sym* elemento);

/* Permite sacar el primer elemento de la pila */
void* pop(Stack* pila);

/* Indica si una pila no contiene elementos */
bool is_empty(Stack* pila);

/* Permite liberar la memoria que utiliza la pila */
void free_stack(Stack* pila);

/*Permite ver el elemento al tope de la pila*/
sym *top(Stack* pila);
```

produccion.h file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _production prod;
```

Any thoughts or observations? Thanks

Comment: did you run it through a debugger and see where the segfault occurs?  you might be surprised

Comment: How do I do that? I'm sorry, C is a brand new lenguage to me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749834/segmentation-fault-with-gdb-debugger-c should get you started

Comment: A more specific question would help. Is your question what causes segmentation faults? Is it how to debug them? (If so, you need to tell us what debugger or platform you have.) If you're expecting us to find the bug, you need to strip down your code to the minimum necessary and sufficient to replicate the bug. We can't find bugs in code we can't see and the code you've shown is pretty minimal, missing header files, no way to call it, and so on.

Comment: I was just asking if I defined in a correct way the elements of the structure, because reading tutorials I encountered that I must use . for each type of the structure

Comment: What are you really asking about, to get a review of your code, or help with the crash? For a review of ***working*** code (a hard requirement) then post on [the Code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead. For help with the crash please include a [mcve] and if possible use a debugger to locate where it happens in your code and point out that location to us. Also please take some time to refresh ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that things like `sym *OR = {TERM,"v",2};` isn't valid C, it's just gibberish. You can't initialize a struct *pointer* with a struct initializer list. It needs to point at an actual object. So just drop the `*` pointer declaration, why do you need these to be pointers for?

This is why beginners should always compile with a conforming standard C compiler. I recommend using

`gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`

which would have pointed out the bug for you (unlike default gcc which accepts lots of invalid code). It's much easier to resolve compile-time errors than run-time seg faults.